# Utilizing meta-data in Elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch

Can Elasticsearch utilize meta-data to improve queries? For example,

- popularity of an object (number of people who requested it)
- remembering previous search term (e.g. if someone searched doggg then chose the dog page, then the next time someone searches doggg, dog should be ranked higher in the query results)

If it's not possible, what other tools might be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of metadata can be used in a positive feedback system to improve search but Elasticsearch does not by itself store this kind of data; you will need to build a system to do this. As a couple of examples:

> popularity of an object (number of people who requested it)

This could be achieved by indexing the popularity value into a field on the document and using a [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) with a [field value factor function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) to take the popularity into account when calculating a relevancy score.

> remembering previous search term (e.g. if someone searched doggg then chose the dog page, then the next time someone searches doggg, dog should be ranked higher in the query results)

You could index search terms for a given user, along with the actual term selected and use this as an input into the search that you perform for a user. You could take advantage of a [terms suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html) to provide suggestions for input terms based on the available terms within the corpus of documents. Terms suggester can be useful for providing spelling corrections guided by available terms.